# C batch processing data and main thread wait for all sub-threads

Tags: c, multithreading, events, synchronization

Description:
1. There is one main thread, and 8 sub-threads, all these threads are executed in loop, don't need to exit. 
2. These 8 sub-threads will set a global variable, then in main thread need to read this global variable.
3. Main thread needs to wait all these 8 sub-threads to finish running one cycle. Every sub-thread has a event.

Pseudo-code:
sub-thread:

```
While(1) {
    do_something1();
    set_global_variable;
    set_event;
    sleep(100);
}
```

main thread:

```
While(1) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        wait_event[event[i]];
    }

    read_global_variable;
    do_something2();
    sleep(100)
}
```

My question:
I need to realize as follows.
When event of one sub-thread is set, the sub-thread should be suspend until all these 8 sub-threads' event are set, and main thread executed read_global_variable, then the sub-thread can start to run again. That is the main thread needs to control the execution of sub-threads.
But i cannot process it better. How to realize it? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I know i can use thread pool to realize it, but i want to know how to do it if not use thread pool...

Comment: The main thread after `read_global_variable` just needs to set an event, that the sub thread needs to be listen on (wait_event). I cannot help more, we do not know the target or the OS, this is kind of architecture specific...